# Delete old files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash

How can I delete all files that are older than one year in a specific folder with the bash under Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;

vi samefilename 
#!/bin/bash

find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

The only 2 commands used are find and rm.

Find looks for files (-type f), this to exclude directories, that are older then 3 days (-mtime +3). All it finds is given to rm (-exec rm {} \; ).

You could also place the rm statement outside of find, which is supposed to be faster:

find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +3 | xargs rm

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `\;` with `find` for perfomance similar to `xargs`.

Comment: Also, when using *xargs*, please do it as `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` (if available) so that pathnames with spaces (and even embedded line feed characters) are handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

another approach I found.
nice for specific dates.

```
touch --date="2010-1-1" x
find -not -newer x|xargs rm
```

Answer (score 1):

**tmpwatch** does a good job, example:

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch $[24*365] /tmp
```

Exerpt from manual:

> tmpwatch  recursively  removes files
>   which haven’t been accessed for a
>   given number of hours. Normally, it’s
>   used to clean up directories which are
>   used for temporary holding space such
>   as /tmp.

```
tmpwatch [-u|-m|-c] [-MUadfqstvx] [--verbose] [--force] [--all]
                  [--nodirs] [--nosymlinks] [--test] [--fuser] [--quiet]
                  [--atime|--mtime|--ctime] [--dirmtime] [--exclude <path>]
                  [--exclude-user <user>] <hours> <dirs>
```

Answer (score 0):

tmpwatcher or "tmpreaper" in ubuntu.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tmpwatch.htm

use with -c